# Limit involving the exponential of an expression plus a small-o

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to formalize the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[1+\frac{a}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right]^x= e^a$$
however I can't see how to rigorously show this identity. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try showing the logarithm of this identity.

Comment: For any $\epsilon>0$, can you show that it is greater than $e^{a-\epsilon}$ and less than $e^{a+\epsilon}$?

Comment: Ok, I've solved it using @QiaochuYuan's hint, re-expanding with Taylor the logarithm etc. Thanks :)

Comment: @robjohn Yep, now I see... I had just to apply the definition... I have to be ashamed by the mental lazyness that brings me to ask somebody before to ask myself one more time... Thank you

Comment: the one trickiness about using my hint is that you should use $\liminf$ and $\limsup$.

Comment: yes, I meant the definition of little-o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've solved it using Qiaochu's logarithm hint, let's try another way. I am guessing that you already know that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[1+\frac{a}{x}\right]^x=e^a\tag{1}
$$
and that the new twist is the little-o term.  Little-o here means that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $M>0$ so that for $x>M$
$$
\left|o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\le\frac{\epsilon}{x}\tag{2}
$$
Condition $(2)$ means that for $x>M$
$$
\left[1+\frac{a-\epsilon}{x}\right]^x\le\left[1+\frac{a}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^x\le\left[1+\frac{a+\epsilon}{x}\right]^x\tag{3}
$$
Inequalities $(3)$ imply that
$$
e^{a-\epsilon}\le\liminf_{x\to\infty}\left[1+\frac{a}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^x\le\limsup_{x\to\infty}\left[1+\frac{a}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^x\le e^{a+\epsilon}\tag{4}
$$
and since inequalities $(4)$ hold for any $\epsilon>0$, we have that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[1+\frac{a}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^x=e^a
$$
Note that we cannot apply the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) to $(3)$ because the limits of the upper and lower bounds are not equal. Since $\epsilon>0$, $e^{a-\epsilon}\not=e^{a+\epsilon}$; however, since $\epsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small, $(4)$ allows us to squeeze the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ together to produce a limit.

Comment: I am confused about the need for the inferior and superior limits. After attaining (3), doesn't the Squeeze theorem establish not just the value, but the existence of the limit as well?

Comment: In $(3)$, we have chosen a **fixed** $\epsilon$, which gives us $M$. All we know is that for $x>M$, $\left[1+\frac{a}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^x$ is somewhere between $\left[1+\frac{a-\epsilon}{x}\right]^x$ and $\left[1+\frac{a+\epsilon}{x}\right]^x$, but it could be *anywhere* between those two values. The limit of the lower bound is $e^{a-\epsilon}$ and the limit of the upper bound is $e^{a+\epsilon}$, so as $x\to\infty$, $\left[1+\frac{a}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^x$ could be bouncing around between those values. So $(3)$ only gives a bound on $\liminf$ and $\limsup$.

Comment: @Ragib: However, $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily small, so $(4)$ says that $\liminf=\limsup$, so the limit exists and is equal to them. The Squeeze theorem only holds if the limits of the two bounds are equal, which they are not here.

Comment: Aah thank you @robjohn, I didn't absorb that subtlety even when looking for one! Perhaps you could incorporate your comments into the answer, it may inform other people like me.

Comment: @Ragib: so incorporated.