# convergence to exponential with order 1/n

Tags: real-analysis, probability, complex-analysis

We know that  limit $\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n$ converges to $e^x$ but how can we prove that limit $\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}+o(\frac{1}{n})\right)^n$ converges to $e^x$.

Comment: what does $o(1/n)$ represent?

Comment: O(1/n) represents the order of 1/n terms .

Comment: Don't make a mess with $o$ and $O.$

Comment: Actually i also have some confusion with these notations o and O and their meaning. Can you suggest some link where should i get these things.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374747/if-z-n-to-z-then-1z-n-nn-to-ez

Comment: Please, "limits" do not "converge", sequences converge (or not) and (when they converge) limits are equal to something.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(n)=o(1/n)$.

Choose any $\epsilon\gt0$. There is an $N$ so that if $n\ge N$, then $\left|f(n)\right|\le\epsilon/n$. Therefore,
$$
e^{x-\epsilon}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x-\epsilon}n\right)^n\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn+f(n)\right)^n\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x+\epsilon}n\right)^n=e^{x+\epsilon}
$$
Since $\epsilon\gt0$ was arbitrary, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn+f(n)\right)^n=e^x
$$

---

As gniourf_gniourf mentions, we also need to choose $N$ big enough so that for $n\ge N$,
$$
1+\frac{x-\epsilon}{n}\ge0
$$
since $x\le y\implies x^n\le y^n$ when $x,y\ge0$.

Comment: How do you justify
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac{x-\varepsilon}n\right)^n\leq\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac xn+f(n)\right)^n?$$
you must also mention that you take $n$ sufficiently large for $\dfrac{x-\varepsilon}n$ to be greater than $-1$ so that you're in the domain where $t\mapsto t^n$ is increasing.

Comment: Valid point. I've incorporated it.

Answer (score 1):

For $\alpha_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}+\alpha_n\right)^n=e^{\lim_{n\to \infty} (x+n\alpha_n)}=e^x,$$ where in the last equality we have used that $\alpha_n=o(1/n),$ that is, $\lim_n n\alpha_n=0.$

**Edit**

- Justification of the identity used:

Assume $\alpha_n\to 0, \beta_n\to \infty$ and that $\lim_n\to \infty$ exits. Since $e=\lim_n (1+\alpha_n)^{1/\alpha_n}$ we have that

$$\displaystyle \lim_n (1+\alpha_n)^{\beta_n}=\lim_n (1+\alpha_n)^{ \frac{\alpha_n\beta_n}{\alpha_n}}=\left(\lim_n (1+\alpha_n)^{1/\alpha_n}\right)^{\lim_n \alpha_n\beta_n}=e^{\lim_n \alpha_n\beta_n}.$$

- $o()$-notation:

$\alpha_n=o(1/n)$ means, by definition, that $\lim_n \frac{\alpha_n}{1/n}=0.$ But $\lim_n \frac{\alpha_n}{1/n}=\lim_n n\alpha_n$ and so it exists and is $0.$

Comment: Can you show me how αn=o(1/n) implies limnnαn=0.

Comment: I have done it in the answer.

Comment: And i want a proof for this thing using $e^x$ and the the limit of the above term tending to zero.

Comment: How do you justify that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac xn+\alpha_n\right)^n=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to+\infty}(x+n\alpha_n)\right)?$$

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I have just done it.

Comment: No--you just made a mess with o(1) and o(1/n).

Comment: $\alpha_n\to0$? $n\alpha_n\to0$? Both? None? :-)

Comment: @Did Yes, both limits exist and they are zero. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html

Comment: The problem is in the way you present things, not in the result or in definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$. Then:
$$\left(1+\frac xn+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)^n=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac xn+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\right).$$
Now, since
$$\dfrac xn+o\left(\dfrac1n\right)\underset{n\to+\infty}\longrightarrow0$$
and
$$o\left(\dfrac xn+o\left(\dfrac1n\right)\right)\underset{n\to+\infty}=o\left(\dfrac 1n\right),$$
we have
$$\ln\left(1+\frac xn+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\underset{n\to+\infty}=\frac xn+o\left(\frac1n\right),$$
hence
$$n\ln\left(1+\frac xn+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\underset{n\to+\infty}=x+o(1),$$
hence
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\ln\left(1+\frac xn+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=x.$$
Now you can conclude by composing by the exponential function (which is continuous).