# Limit, L’Hopital, inverse trig function

Tags: calculus, limits

The question is: evaluate 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\arctan(x)}\right).$$
Please check my work:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\arctan(x)}\right)
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)-x}{x\arctan(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)-x}{\arctan(x)}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}
\\=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1}{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}=0\cdot \infty.$$

Comment: You’re familiar with our standards for asking questions, correct?

Comment: Since the function is odd, the limit (if it exists) must be $0$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the limit is the same, but here the question involves L'Hopital and there is about the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @RobertZ: There is [one answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1633239/42969) using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @MartinR That answer is not very useful here, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using L'Hospital 's rule you missed part of the denominator. 
Check your work and continue with taking common denominator and one more L'Hospital to get the answer. 
My answer is $0$ see if I have the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

After reading your work, I think that it is easier if you proceed in this way
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\arctan(x)}\right)=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)-x}{x\arctan(x)}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)-x}{x^2}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\arctan(x)}.$$
Now apply L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Much simpler !!!

Answer (score 0):

$$\bigg[x\tan^{-1}x\bigg]' = x\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\tan^{-1}x=\frac{x+(x^2+1)\tan^{-1}x}{1+x^2}$$
$$\bigg[x+(x^2+1)\tan^{-1}x\bigg]'=1+1+2x\tan^{-1}x$$
On applying L' Hopital twice, $$l=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-x^2}{x+(x^2+1)\tan^{-1}x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-2x}{2x\tan^{-1}x+2}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\arctan\left(x\right)}\right)$$
Step 1:Simplify
$$\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\arctan \left(x\right)-x}{x\arctan \left(x\right)}\right)$$
Step 2: L'Hopitale's rule
$$\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{x^2+1}-1}{\arctan \left(x\right)+\frac{x}{x^2+1}}\right)$$
Step 3:Simplify
$$\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(-\frac{x^2}{\arctan \left(x\right)\left(x^2+1\right)+x}\right)$$
Step 4:L'Hopitale's Rule
$$\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{-2x}{2x\arctan \left(x\right)+2}\right)$$
Step 5: Plug in value of $x$. You will get answer as $0$