# prove $\left(\frac{1}{\arctan x}-\frac1x\right)\lt x$ for $x\gt 0$

Tags: analysis

How to prove $\left(\frac{1}{\arctan x}-\frac1x\right)\lt x$ for $x\gt 0$ without the method of using its derivative? 
It appeared as a part of a math paper. The author said it could be easily proven by its Taylor's series. But I couldn't figure it out.

Revision: I am sorry for the confusion of using Taylor's series but not its derivative. 
The original paper said that

> Prove $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \left( \cfrac{1}{arctanx}-\frac{1}{x} \right) = 0$$
>
> Substituting arctan *x* by its Taylor's series yields:
>
> $$\frac{1}{\arctan x}-\frac 1x\ = \frac{x-arctan x}{x\cdot arctan x} = \cfrac{x-\left(x-\cfrac{x^3}{3}+\cfrac{x^5}{5}\cdots\right)}{x\cdot \left(x-\cfrac{x^3}{3}+\cfrac{x^5}{5}\cdots\right)}=x\cdot\cfrac{\cfrac 13-\cfrac{x^2}{5}+\cdots}{1-\cfrac{x^2}{3}+\cdots}\longrightarrow 0$$
>   as $x \longrightarrow 0$, since the limit of the fraction is $1/3$.
>
> the inequality can be easily extracted from the proof above. Here is another, independent, proof. Consider function $f(x)=\left(1+x^2\right)arctanx-x$. Since $f(x)=2x arctanx \gt0$ for $x\gt0$ and $f(0)=0$, we have $f(x)\gt0$ for all $x\gt0$

So, I was trying to ask how the inequality could be proved by another method rather than the "independent" method using derivative given by the author. 
Sincere apology for the incomplete question.

Comment: How can it be proven without using its derivative if it says you can use Taylor series?

Comment: Taylor Series involve derivatives. I've posted an answer that avoids use of derivatives and relies on only elementary (i.e., pre-calculus) analysis.  Using that analysis shows that $$\frac1{\arctan(x)}-\frac1x<\frac x2$$Interestingly, using derivatives, we can show $$\frac1{\arctan(x)}-\frac1x<\frac x3$$

Comment: @battletwink69  Sorry for the misleading question. I have updated the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite it as $$ \frac{1}{\arctan x} < \frac{1}{x}+x$$
$$ \arctan x > \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
Let $x=\tan y$, $y\in(0,\frac\pi 2)$. We need to show that
$$ y > \frac{\tan y}{1+ \tan^2 y}= \frac{\sin y\cos y}{\cos^2y+\sin^2 y} = \frac12\sin 2y$$
That is $$ 2y > \sin 2y$$
which is a well known fact.

Answer (score 1):

Using elementary (i.e., pre-calculus) analysis only in [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624420/limit-lim-x-to-inftyx-tan-1fx-xgx/1624595#1624595), I developed the bounds

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \le \arctan(x)\le x} \tag1$$

for $x\ge 0$.

Rearranging $(1)$, we see that for $x>0$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\arctan(x)}-\frac1x&\le \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-1}{x}\\\\
&= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}\\\\
&< \frac x2\\\\
&<x
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

So, from $(1)$ we actually found the much tighter bound

$$\frac1{\arctan(x)}-\frac1x < \frac x2$$

---

And interestingly, using derivatives, we can show that

$$\frac1{\arctan(x)}-\frac1x\le \frac x3$$

Comment: Hi @orionzhang Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Please feel free to accept and up vote an answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequalitiy simplifies to $$x^2\arctan(x)-x+\arctan(x)>0$$ let
$$f(x)=x^2\arctan(x)-x+\arctan(x)$$ then $$f'(x)=2x\arctan(x)+\frac{x^2-x^2-1+1}{x^2+1}>0$$ and $$f(0)=0$$

Comment: Is that *“without the method of using its derivative”*?