# Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\tan^{-1}x=\pi/2$

Tags: limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I have recently started studying limits when I came across this question:

> Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \tan^{-1}x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ using $\epsilon-\delta$ approach.

This question was given as exercise and I have approached it in this way:

***My Appraoch:***

Suppose $\Big|\tan^{-1}x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Big|<\epsilon$

Now $x>0$ since $x\rightarrow \infty$, this means that the maximum value of $\Big|\tan^{-1}x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Big|$ is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

When $\epsilon>\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, then the $\epsilon$-inequality is valid for any $x>0$

When $\epsilon<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, then: $$\tan^{-1}x>\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon$$
$$x>\tan\Big(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon\Big)$$

Thus for any $0<\delta\leq\tan\Big(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon\Big)$, we would have $x>\delta$ which implies that $\Big|\tan^{-1}x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Big|<\epsilon$.

$\therefore \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \tan^{-1}x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Please help me verify this solution and please offer some suggestions.

***THANKS***

Comment: Do you want to show for all $\epsilon$ there is $X$ such that if $x>X$ then $|\tan^{-1}x-\dfrac \pi 2|<\epsilon$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, exactly that

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Is it correct?

Comment: If you're trying to *show* $|\arctan x-(\pi/2)|<\epsilon$, then you can't start a proof by *assuming* $|\arctan x-(\pi/2)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Also, for limits at infinity, epsilon-delta approach doesn't make sense, as it's impossible for the distance from $x$ to infinity to be less than delta. You need an $X$-epsilon approach, as in @J.W.Tanner comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm sorry for I may have misstated the approach but that was exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Good. Try to do it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x>0$, then

$$\arctan(x)=\pi/2-\arctan(1/x)\tag1$$

In [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624420/limit-lim-x-to-inftyx-tan-1fx-xgx/1624595#1624595), I showed using elementary analysis only that for $x>0$

$$\arctan(x)\le x\tag2$$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ reveals that for any given $\varepsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}\left|\arctan(x)-\frac \pi2\right|&=\left|\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)\right|\\\\
&\le \frac1x\\\\
&<\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $x>\frac1\varepsilon$.  And we are done!

Comment: A great approach indeed. Thanks for help (+1)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.