# Is $(1+ z_n/n)^n - e^{z_n} $ always negative for $n \geq 2$ when $ \frac{z_n}{n} \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, logarithms, exponential-function

This question is similar to
[If $z_n \to z$ then $(1+z_n/n)^n \to e^z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374747/if-z-n-to-z-then-1z-n-nn-to-ez)

In this case $z_n$ does not converge but $ \frac{z_n}{n} \rightarrow 0 $.

Comment: Of course not. Let $(z_n)$ be the sequence $0,-100, 0, 0, 0, \dots.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$\ln\left[(1+z_n/n)^n\right]
=n\ln(1+z_n/n)=z_n-\frac{z_n^2}{2n}+\cdots.$$
This will usually be less than $z_n$ eventually.

Comment: Does that eventually happen at $n = 2 $ for  $z_n = \log(n)$?
I understand when $ z_n = \sqrt{n}$, then it will happen at $n = \inf$