# How do I calculate the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1-\frac{\theta^2}{2n^2})^{2(n+1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, approximation

I'm going through some physics problems about polarizers and one problem is about the case where $n+1$ polarizers are stacked up and I have to look at the case where $n \to \infty$.

Now I came up for a solution for the intensity in the case of $n+1$ polarizers: $$I_{n+1}=I_0*\left(\cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right)\right)^{n+1}$$

Doing the Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$ I get: $$I_{n+1}=I_0*\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{2n^2}\right)^{2(n+1)}$$

I know that the limit of this as $n \to\infty$ should be just $I_0$, but I don't really know how to get to that result.
I also saw someone saying that $$\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{2n^2}\right)^{2(n+1)} \approx e^{-\theta^2/(n+1)}$$ which would indeed give me $1$ as $n \to \infty $ but I don't want to use something that I don't fully understand how to get to.

Would be really great if someone could help me out!
Thank you!

Comment: For a more general result, see [If $z_n \to z$ then $(1+z_n/n)^n \to e^z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374747). (Paramanand Singh's answer is particularly nice, I think.) Indeed, that lemma can be applied directly to the original form $\left(\cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{n}\right)\right)^{n+1} \to 1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take logarithms:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2(n+1)\ln(1-\theta^2/2n^2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}2(n+1)(-\theta^2/2n^2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-\theta^2/n)=0,$$with repeated uses of $f(n)\sim1\to\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)g(n)$. So the original limi is $e^0=1$.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! That was fast. I can't exactly see how you got to this one: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}2(n+1)\ln(1-\theta^2/2n^2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}2(n+1)(-\theta^2/2n^2)$$ How did you get rid of the logarithm and the $1$? I've honestly never seen this trick with applying the logarithm before, so I'm a little bit puzzled...

Comment: @markus As $n\to\infty$, $-\theta^2/2n^2\to0$; as $x\to0$, $\ln(1+x)\sim x$.

Comment: Alright, now I get it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{2n^2}\right)^{2(n+1)}=\lim\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{2n^2}\right)^{2n^2/n}\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}{2n^2}\right)^2=\left(e^{-\theta^2}\right)^{\lim 1/n}1^2=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way:
$$
\left(1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2n^2}\right)^{2(n + 1)} =
\left(1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2n^2}\right)^2
\left(1 + \frac{\theta\sqrt2}{2n}\right)^{2n}
\left(1 - \frac{\theta\sqrt2}{2n}\right)^{2n} \to
1^2 \cdot e^{\theta\sqrt2} \cdot e^{-\theta\sqrt2} = 1.
$$